# Flags of svchost

Tags: windows, windows-10, svchost

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067914/what-does-the-k-flag-in-svchost-k-means), the `-k` flag is to specify the group name of `svchost` process, but I find that on my system, the `-p` option is used also in many services. For example the DPS (Diagnostic Policy Service) is started by

```
C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNoNetwork -p
```

So what does `-p` mean?

Answer (score 1):

There is a detail [write-up](https://pusha.be/index.php/2020/05/07/exploration-of-svchost-exe-p-flag/) about this flag, citing it verbatim:

> P flag enforces different policies: DynamicCodePolicy,
> BinarySignaturePolicy and ExtensionPolicy.